# Android - get the number of friends from Facebook JSON endpoint - android

Tags: android, json, facebook

I have a JSON endpoint on facebook that returns the email, birthday and other parameters of the authenticated user. My challenge is to be able to get the number of friends from the JSON endpoint. Below is my snippet

```
private void FaceBookLogin() {
        fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                // App code
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                // Application code
                                Log.v("Profile ---------   ", response.toString());
                                Log.v("Object ---------   ", object.toString());

                                try {
                                    Name = object.getString("name");
                                    Email = object.getString("email");
                                    DOB = object.getString("birthday");
                                    FRIENDSCOUNT= object.getString("parameterhere"); //here is the challenge
                                    Log.v("Email = ", " " + Email);
                                    Log.v("PUBLIC PROFILE = ", " " + PUBLICPROFILE);
                                    //                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name " + Name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
```

Please, how can I get the number of friends of a user from the above snippet?

Comment: i told you in that other thread that you need to do another api call to the /me/friends endpoint. please do not create 2 separate threads for one question, edit the other one instead to include more information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fetch the number of invitable friends when you hit the graph api request.

```
/* make the API call */

GraphRequest request =  new GraphRequest(
 loginResult.getAccessToken(),
"/{user-id}/friends",
null,
HttpMethod.GET,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
           Log.v("Profile ---------   ", response.toString());
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

and you can print this response in console , and fetch the desired result.

Comment: please how can I implement this in my code. Its slightly different from what I am doing

Comment: you need to add this inside you onSuccess method

Comment: do not have on success method in the activity. do i show the complete activity

Comment: i added little work flow code in answer , use this in your code.

Comment: as per your question , if you want to know the friends of a user from facebook , this code will help you . after getting the friends number you can do the needful

Comment: but that is my snippet and how can merge my codes with yours is the challenge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161909/discussion-between-thunder-and-float).

Comment: invitable_friends would be wrong, it is /me/friends to get the total amount of friends. invitable_friends only returns a list of invite tokens for friends, to invite them to an app.